# How can I use .net 7 navigationlock component in .net 6 using blazor?

Tags: blazor

How can I use dotnet 7 navigationlock component in dotnet 6?

I want to use method about window back key event call.

If you know, Please let me know.

Comment: Didn't you see my comment on your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430747/how-can-i-control-back-button-event-in-blazor.  No time travel here.  If you want Net7 features, upgrade.

Comment: Eh?  You know that bigger numbers mean new versions with new stuff, right?  Why do you think that .net 6 would support .net 7 features?